# Отобразить значения в массиве при Foreach

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
    foreach ($cvets as $cvet):
    echo  $cvet->name. ' ';
    endforeach;
```

Выводит: `красный черный` Записываю значение `$cvet->name. ' '` в массив, вот так:

```
$mymassive = $cvet->name. ' ';
```

Далее отображаю вот так `echo $mymassive;` Но в результате выводит только `черный`, а не все. Как отобразить все значения в массиве `$mymassive` ?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что $mymassive  это массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($cvets as $cvet):
    $mymassive.=$cvet->name.' '; // конечно это строка а не массив
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь вам надо обозначить переменную как массив:

```
$mymassive = array();

    foreach ($cvets as $cvet):
      array_push($mymassive,$cvet->name)
     endforeach;
```

Comment: не обязательно обозначать массив. Можно вставлять просто так  $mymassive[]=$cvet->name;

Comment: @Nsk а чем вам не подуше красивое $mymassive = array(); ?

Comment: зачем лишние строки в коде не несущие смысловой нагрузки? Да и дальнейший $mymassive[]=$cvet->name; компактнее выглядит.

Comment: `$mymassive.=$cvet->name.' ';` вот так не правильно? Работает.

Comment: @ЮляФролова  так правильно если вам на выходе нужна только строка для echo

Comment: @Nsk смысл такого примера что бы автору было более понятно...

Comment: @ЮляФролова вы в вопросе писали о получения массива, $mymassive.=$cvet->name.' ' - это будет строка

Comment: Мне нужно для `str_replace`

Comment: @ЮляФролова str_replace это что? Замена строки - значит нужна строка

Comment: @Arsen, мое мнение такое - если спрашивают код для копипастнуть то лучше давать чистый и компактный код, если для обучения то лучше учить сразу современный пхп, а не древние =array(), array_push(). Вот сам пытаюсь отойти от древнего синтаксиса, но рецидивы не редки.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, очень помогли!